# Energy conservation when exchanging meson

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, strong-force, mesons

In Prob 1.2 of Griffith's "Introduction to Elementary Particles" 2nd ed., it says that:

[image: Prob 1.2 of Griffith's "Introduction to Elementary Particles" 2nd ed.]

However, I don't understand why it states that "they must temporarily **violate the conservation of energy** by an amount $mc^2$ (the rest energy of the meson)". If my understanding is correct, the "missing" energy was just temporary stored in the  meson while exchanging, and therefore the energy is still conserved if we consider the system including the 2 interacting protons and the meson exchanged. So, is the energy conservation law really violated in this case? If true, where and why it is violated?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221842/why-do-many-people-say-that-virtual-particles-do-not-conserve-energy

Comment: Yes, I know that the virtual particle need not obeys the energy conservation. However, in this particular problem, it just seems doesn't violate the conservation of energy by an amount $mc^2$ if we consider the meson (though we know it's not exactly the case in reality)

Comment: *the "missing" energy was just temporary stored in the meson* That doesn't really help though, because the (rest) mass of a pion is much larger than the mass difference between a neutron & a proton.