# What is virtual particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, virtual-particles

I am trying to understand what a virtual particle is, but it have been proved to be very hard. There is so many different defination of the virtual particles that i am getting very confused and frustrated! I know that some are created by the uncertainty principle, but that don't tell me much!

1. What is a virtual particle? Do not say that they are ripples or a disturbance in a field, because that does not tell me anything! I have heard that they are not a particle, is this true?
2. I have also heard that thay are not real? How can something exist if they are not real?
3. Also, i have heard that they are created in pair, why is it so? Is it because  everything need an anti / negative counterpart of itself?
4. Why is it so that the longer they exist, the more like a real particle they becomes?
5. The particles in quantum field theories, are those virtual or real? For example in quantum electrodynamics (the exchanging photons), i have read somewhere that they are virtual, and some other places that they are real? So what are they?
6. The virtual particles that appears in the vacuum because of the uncertainty principle / quantum fluctuation, are those virtual photons?

I am just 15 years, but i am really proud of the things i do know. Please keep it simple and do not include any equations.  Thanks for your time, i really appreciate that :)

Comment: The only language available for describing virtual particles are either analogous words like 'ripples' that you dislike, or mathematics, but then you say 'keep it simple and do not include equations'. So what do you actually want? The rest of the questions are addressed in virtually any introductory text on QFT...

Comment: Your question (4) may reverse cause and effect. The more like a real particle they are, the longer they are likely to exist.

Comment: Have you seen Professor Strassler's explanation on virtual particles?   I think it's pretty good and he does it without equations.    He does, however, mention ripples and disturbances in a field though, but worth a look:   https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/

Comment: Have a look at this answer of mine  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286721/what-actually-are-virtual-particles/286728#286728

Comment: Aside from the linked duplicate, see also e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230113/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/205674/50583 and other questions tagged [tag:virtual-particles]