# How do we know sound cannot travel in a quantum vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vacuum, phonons

This is probably bad wording and I apologize.

I mean the quantum vacuum in space that is made of a soup of emerging/vanishing pairs of particles.

More generally, why sound (phonons) is assumed to not propagate in such a vacuum?

I mean, if there are particles even shortly lived, is the density too low to transmit information to each other?

Or is it something else? Like virtual particles and not actual particles that could interact with each other.

Also, if this quantum vacuum is the zero point field energy, am I wrong to assume there could be phonons in that sea, although not observable at our level? Or is it assumed to be completely random with no inner network?

Comment: This question is based on the premise that particles "pop in and out of existence" in the QFT vacuum. This is wrong, as discussed many times on this site. See e.g. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205674/virtual-particles-real-virtual-particles-create-a-universe). Arnold Neumaier wrote extensively about this, e.g. [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/vacuum-fluctuation-myth/).

Comment: Thanks for the links.